# Typescript compiler error - pass in an object's property of MyType to an attribute which only accepts MyType

Tags: angular, typescript

Consider the following HTML:

```
<my-menu-item [item]='item'>
  <my-icon type='item.iconType'></my-icon>
</my-menu-item>
```

The `my-icon` component only accepts an input of type `IconType` as input for the type attribute. Now, the passed in item to `my-menu-item` is a type that contains the property `iconType` which is of type `IconType`. Still, for the above shown HTML, I am getting a compiler error, saying that I cannot pass in `item.iconType` as argument to the `my-icon` type attribute.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I would highly recommend using double quotes for attributes: `[item]="item"`. Aside from that, can you post your component code and interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
<my-menu-item [item]='item'>
  <my-icon type='item.iconType'></my-icon>
</my-menu-item>
```

In this code you're missing the `[]` around type : `[type]="item.iconType"`

I will assume this a typo on your part.

As for the question, be sure that your item implements this :

```js
type IconType = 'png' | 'jpg'; // Your types
interface Icon {
  iconType: IconType
}
```

And that your `MyIconComponent` has this :

```js
@Input() type!: IconType;
```

Comment: I was missing the brackets... thx so much!